# convergence of series in Rudin 3.11

Tags: real-analysis

If $a_n$ is positive reals and $\sum a_n$ is diverging,is$\sum a_n/(1+n a_n)$ diverging or not? It may diverge since if $a_n=1$ then it is diverging.

Comment: What if $a_n = 1$ if $n$ is a perfect square, and $a_n = 0$ otherwise?

Comment: great answer thanks.